# Schema Core - 404

Tags: dxa, schema

We have a snippet of code in our footer of:

```
<nav prefix="go: http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core" typeof="go:FooterConfiguration">
```

The prefix of go to the schema core is 404ing. Any ideas whether it is needed by webapp or where it should go too?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean with "The prefix of go to the schema core is 404ing""?

Comment: Yes, so if you go to http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core it is returning a 404 error. This is being picked up on our website. What we are trying to establish is what is that prefix/URL, if it is needed and if it is needed how do we fix it so it isn't going to an error page. I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the `prefix` and `typeof` HTML attributes are so-called [RDFa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa) attributes: these are used to specify the semantics of HTML elements (which themselves tend to be more formatting-oriented).

More specifically: these attributes allow you to map HTML elements to semantic types or properties which are defined in a public *Vocabulary* (such as [Schema.org](http://schema.org/)).

In your case, they are referring to the Vocabulary with URI `http://www.sdl.com/web/schemas/core`.  This is *not* a public Vocabulary, but used internally by DXA to do semantic mapping to CM Schemas.  It does not make sense to use this as a public Vocabulary.

The reason why this happens is because your View Models have a `SemanticEntity` annotation that declares the "SDL Core" vocabulary as Public. I see people doing that a lot, but it does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Just to confirm, do we need to have it at all? I am guessing we do so the DXA can do the semantic mapping to CM Schemas?

Comment: You may or may not need `SemanticEntity` and `SemanticProperty` attributes to do the semantic mapping to CM Schemas.  DXA can do implicit mapping too. For more info, see the [DXA docs](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v10/GUID-C0AD6DCC-ED65-441F-B361-928A18B2896D)

Comment: Thank you, we will take a look at the documentation and work it out